# Cloning a private GitHub repo using Atom

Tags: clone, github, repository, atom-editor

I'm trying to clone a private GitHub repo that I'm the owner of using Atom text editor. Using the GitHub:Clone command, I enter a URL like: https://github.com/orgname/reponame , and I receive an error as such:

Unable to clone https://github.com/orgname/reponame
Cloning into 'some directory'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/orgname/reponame/'
not found

How can I clone this repo in Atom?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the clone command with SSH key. It is not only a problem with Github. Also a selfhosted Git server cause porblems with private repositories. 
See the Link below for help with the SSH key on Github: 
https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/